# Is it possible to cancel an uplift project?

Tags: stellaris

I started an uplift project but picked the wrong traits for the species. Is it possible to change the traits or cancel the project and choose different ones?

Comment: Is there not a "Cancel" option in the log?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you click the "Cancel" button in the situation log, the project will "time out" after 90 days, and the genetic modification points get refunded.

At that point you can start a new project with the traits you want.